# How to access last column field with Python and increase by 1 in .csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv consisting of 2 columns and a bunch of data.  I have the following so far which generates a csv:

```
name    values

0   1

1   2

2   1

3   0

4   -1

5   0

6   1

7   1

8   2

9   3

10  3
```

... etc and continues for 90 rows.
I then have the following code which will remove the first row, and append a NEW row at the bottom of my csv.

The problem with the last row is that I need the first column to be the prior number, but incremented by 1.  The second column's data is irrelevant at this point.  How do I access the first column but increase it by 1?  So far when I've tried to access it I seem to be grabbing the whole row, which isn't what I want.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a wall of code, mostly unrelated to your problem, and in addition, it's missing the actual CSV file. You should provide a ["Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable) Example"](http://sscce.org) (and an excerpt of your data). Otherwise, everyone will click the question, go TL;DR and leave the question.

Comment: Thanks for the input -- hopefully this is bit more clear..

Comment: That's not a CSV file, though. There are lots of empty line, and there are no commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you want to do.  Do you just want the new line's first column to be one more than the old last line's first column?

```
data.append([data[-1][0]+1, newRandomValue])
```

Data's last line is indexed from the end data[-1], the zero'th item [0] in that list is the first column